# Azure Devops - How to refer/read a specific script from other yaml in the main yaml template?

Tags: shell, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, devops

i have below two yaml template

test-template.yml

```
jobs:
   
   -job: Pytest

    steps:
    - task: UsepythonVersion
      displayName: 'Pytest1'
      inputs:
        verion_secific: some_pthon_version
        script: pytest -v tests -k "pretest_case1"

jobs:
   
   -job: Pytest

    steps:
    - task: UsepythonVersion
      displayName: 'Pytest2'
      inputs:
        verion_secific: some_pthon_version
        script: pytest -v tests -k "postTest_case2"
```

Main.yaml

```
steps:
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Before inserted step'
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: echo "This step is before the inserted step."

stages
- stage:test_int1
  pool: 
    vmImage : ubuntu

  jobs:
    - template: test-template.yml<Pytest1 >

- stage:test_int2
  pool: 
    vmImage : ubuntu

  jobs:
    - template: test-template.yml<Pytest2 >
```

how to call each "Pytest1" and "Pytest2" respectively in Main.yaml from test-template.yml?

i tried with below script without using python

```
parameters:
- name: jobName
  type: string
- name: proj_name
  type: string

jobs:
- job: ${{ parameters.jobName }}
  steps:
  - script: |
      # Set the test_case_name based on jobName
      if [ "${{ parameters.jobName }}" = "Pytest2" ]; then
        test_case_name="not Pytest2"
      else
        test_case_name="Pytest2"
      fi

      # Run pytest with the computed test_case_name
      pytest -v tests -k "$test_case_name"

      # Capture the exit code of pytest
      exit_code=$?

      # Handle the exit_code as needed (e.g., print a message or exit with an error code)
      if [ $exit_code -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Tests failed"
        exit 1
      fi
```

but it looks like below part not evaluating the if condition even though the value is "Pytest2"

```
 if [ "${{ parameters.jobName }}" = "Pytest2" ]
```

Any right approach?

Answer (score 0):

Looks below code works

```
# test-template.yml

parameters:
- name: jobName
  type: string

jobs:
- job: ${{ parameters.jobName }}
  steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    displayName: ${{ parameters.jobName }}
    inputs:
      versionSpec: some_python_version
      script: |
        if [ "${{ parameters.jobName }}" = "Pytest1" ]; then
          pytest -v tests -k "pretest_case1"
        elif [ "${{ parameters.jobName }}" = "Pytest2" ]; then
          pytest -v tests -k "postTest_case2"
        else
          # Handle any other jobName value or add an error message if needed.
          echo "Invalid jobName: ${{ parameters.jobName }}"
          exit 1
        fi
```

```
# Main.yaml

trigger:
- main

stages:
- stage: test_int1
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu'
  jobs:
    - template: test-template.yml
      parameters:
        jobName: 'Pytest1'

- stage: test_int2
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu'
  jobs:
    - template: test-template.yml
      parameters:
        jobName: 'Pytest2'
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**